# Full Featured Editor CKEditor in Yii2

Tags: yii2, widget, ckeditor

I have installed the [yii2-ckeditor-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget) form [2amigos](http://www.2amigos.us/) and when I select the full preset

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
    'preset' => 'full'
]) ?>
```

it shows me less buttons

[image]

than the Full Featured CKEditor buttons

[image]

What can I do to import all buttons in the ckeditor widget?

Comment: https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/issues/80

Comment: I think most of these plugins are not by default in the widget (example the colour plugin). Maybe I have to import them somehow. I don't know how, yet.

Comment: i have this problem , how to fix?

Comment: Any fix for this??

Comment: you can add full script cdn to your code by this: "cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/full/ckeditor.js"